# Chmod files to recursively give group same permissions as user

Tags: chmod

Is there a unix command to give the group the same permissions as the user currently has on a file-by-file basis recursively for a directory tree? I.e. if a file is user writeable it should become group writeable, otherwise it should not be group writeable and so on.

Answer (score 33):

Kudos to jamessan for showing us g=u.  On my system, this seems to work:

```
chmod -R g=u dir
```

Comment: That also changes the permissions of directories.  The original question specified files.

Comment: @jamessan, which directories are.

Comment: @Mike, just because *nix allows you to treat pretty much everything as a file, doesn't mean that directories actually are files.  Even if one were to concede that they are the same, there is a distinct functional difference between changing the permissions of all files in a directory tree and changing the permissions of all files & directories in a directory tree.

Comment: Once again there is straightforward solution to my problem. Why am I not surprised?

Comment: when I tried this via `sudo`, it didn't work;  I had to switch to the owning user first.

Answer (score 9):

```
find dir -type f -exec chmod g=u '{}' \+
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy way to do that with existing commands. Maybe a script like this would help :

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$1"

find "$DIR" -ls | while read a b perm c d e f g h i file; do
   uperm=${perm:1:3}
   uperm=$(echo "$uperm" | tr -d '-')
   chmod g=$uperm "$file"
done
```

Also, keep in mind that some perms for users might not apply to groups, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if such a command exists but making use of find and invoking it a few times you can achieve
what you are trying to do, for example

For example:

    `% find . -type f -perm -u+w -and ! -perm -g+w -exec chmod g+w {} \;`

The above command traverses the current directory ".", finds all the files that have **write** permission for
the user but no **write**  permissions for the group and changes there permission to be group writable.

Similarly you use variant above invocation to change the file permissions for **read** and **execute**  mode for the group.